# How to check if AutomationElement has focus?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, user-controls, ui-automation

I'm doing integration tests with help of UI Automation. I need to check if a user control has focus (IsFocused = true). Is it possible ? I tried using AutomationElement.FocusedElement, but as far as I checked it returns different control (probably outside of my app).

My control:

```
<UserControl GotFocus="UserControl_GotFocus" Focusable="True">
<DockPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content=">" IsTabStop="False" Focusable="False" Click="TextButton_Click" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" x:Name="textBox" /> 
</DockPanel>
```

code behind:

```
    private void UserControl_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox.Focus();
        Keyboard.Focus(textBox);
    }
```

Comment: AutomationElement.FocusedElement is in general used from outside of your app (plus if you really want to do it you must call it in another thread). Inside you app, you have other ways to determine what has the focus using techniques depending on the UI technology

Comment: I'm ussing it from outside (I'm starting my app from test with Process.Start(processStartInfo);)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `AutomationElement` associated with the control you care about, then get the `AutomationElement.FocusedElement` and compare them. If they are the same, then it is focused.

Also, `AutomationElement.Current` should have a `HasKeyboardFocus` property. You can see if that gives you the information you need.